# Truly Fair Coin

Tags: mathematics, coin-tossing

Is there such a coin – or cylinder – in which there is an equal chance of getting heads, tails or landing on its side?  I am guessing that it is a ratio between the radius and height of the coin, but what are the numbers?

Comment: There was a youtube video that actually tested this a while ago.  They calculated the height two different ways and got two different answers, and experimentally determined that the correct height was somewhere between the two they had calculated.  I don't think it's a trival calculation, since surface area and inertia interact...

Comment: It also depends a lot on how it's flipped. Coin flips are not random processes, careful control of the initial conditions can result in a highly predictable outcome. You'd have to average this performance over all possible flips, since any set of initial conditions could be biased towards heads, tails, or edge, regardless of the coin.

Comment: As @Selvek said, I guess this problem is still an open problem (cmiiw). They had the answer (by complicated formula) but when they experimented it by 3D model, the experiment is not success (they don't share 33.3% - 33.3% - 33.3%). I hope someone give the link for this -- This is what I told several weeks ago.

Comment: I suspect there is a certain amount of chaos involved in the bouncing and such like making it extremely hard to predict how a given shaped object will bounce. With symmetric objects it doesn't really matter how it bounces but if you are talking about a cylinder then a small change to the angle and speed with which it hits a surface can probably make a big difference to the following motion, thus making it hard to predict when a bounce will end with it being on an end or the side...

Comment: This is the video Selvek might have been mentioning. https://youtu.be/-qqPKKOU-yY

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to reinvent the dice.

Comment: I don't think this is on topic here; it isn't really anything to do with creating or solving puzzles.  It's more topical for perhaps Physics.SE, or slightly more relevantly, for Mathematics.SE where it has already been asked:  [What should be the proportions of a three sided coin?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485517)